# Take all my changes on the current branch and move them to a new branch in Git

Tags: git, branch

I started work on what I thought would be a minor bug fix on my master branch. However, it has spiraled out of control to the point where I wish I had created a separate branch to do the development in the first place.

So right now what I'd like to do is:

1. Create a new branch called (say) "edge"
2. Move all the changed / untracked files on master to edge (such that master is unchanged from when I started the bug fix)
3. Finish my work on edge, merge back into master

How can I do this?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

If you haven't been committing anything yet, you're already in the right position.

1. Create a new branch: `git checkout -b edge`
2. Your files haven't changed.  Just `git add` what needs to and commit as usual.
3. When you're done committing on `edge`, switch back to `master` with `git checkout` and `git merge edge`.

Answer (score 88):

To add to JB's answer, if you have *already* started to make a few commits on master for what ended up as being a "edge" effort, you could:

```
git stash
git checkout -b edge master
git branch -f master SHA1_before_your_commits
git stash apply
```

Comment: the stash wrapper is not strictly necessary, but just for uncommitted working changes right?

Comment: @HaveAGuess right. By "take all my changes", I also included current not-yet-added changes. Hence the stash.

Comment: Couldn't the second and third lines be collapsed into "git checkout -b edge master" ?

Comment: @PaulLynch considering those commits (on `master`) that should be on `edge` *are* on `master`, yes. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I don't see how `git stash` is useful here, since using `git checkout -b` does not modify the working tree at all...

Answer (score 13):

If you are trying to move the work from master to a branch that already exists, but is behind master, git won't let you switch to the other branch. In this case, do this:

```
git stash
git checkout oldBranch
git merge master
git checkout master
git stash apply
git checkout oldBranch
```