# Moving from one branch to another with un tracked changes

Tags: git, svn

I am in a suituation where I have unstaged/untracked changes in my repositary and  I want to create and move to a new branch and commit these changes to the new branch, not master.

I found this question on stackoverflow:

[Take all my changes on the current branch and move them to a new branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398329/take-all-my-changes-on-the-current-branch-and-move-them-to-a-new-branch-in-git)

I wasn't able to understand the answer in its eternity.

Basically  what I  understand is that I have to do is:

---

**One**

Add my changes to the stash as git would not allow me to checkout another branch without first committing or stashing my changes

**Two**

Create and checkout the new Branch

**Three**

Apply the stash as a new commit in the new Branch

---

I know how to do one and two but not sure about three

One of the answer given in the above stackoverflow question is :

```
//comments are my understanding on what is happening
//not necessarily true 
git stash                                     //add to stash
git checkout -b edge master                   //create new Bracnh and checkout to it

//Not sure what is happening in the below two lines
git branch -f master SHA1_before_your_commits //reset master to the last commit 
git stash apply              // apply stash to branch,now I can commit to the new branch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just commit your changes, create new branch, and reset the master to the previous commit, e.g.

```
git commit -a
git branch newBranch
git reset --hard HEAD~
git checkout newBranch
```

Comment: won't I loose my changes this way ? I mean when I reset head?

Comment: No, you won't loose your changes. They are safe in branch _newBranch_. Or try it out in a toy repository if you do not believe me.

Answer (score 1):

> I am in a suituation where I have unstaged/untracked changes in my repositary and I want to create and move to a new branch and commit these changes to the new branch, not master.

Using git v2.5 do this:

```
git worktree add <new_path>
```

Now do whatever you want in any of your branches. It will create 2 separate working folders separated from each other while pointing to the same repository.

Using wortree you don't have to do any `clear` or `reset` in order to remove all your staged and untracked content.

Here is demo of how to do it:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer,looking into the documentation of it right now.. trying to understand.Not the sharpest when it comes to git :(

Comment: Cool, pretty simple: you are adding a new directory which points to the same repository but the 3 states are empty. (3 states = working dir, stage area, local repo)

Comment: Feel free to ask anything if you need. ill be back soon if needed.